# How to sort laravel eloquent child relation and get the ordered parent data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here is the model of ProductFilter

```
class ProductFilter extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
    protected $table = 'product_filter';
    protected $fillable = ["filter_id", 'product_id'];
    protected $hidden = [];


    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OcProduct', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Here is the model of the product

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    protected $table = 'product';

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ["product_id", "model",  "image",  "price", "points"];

    protected $hidden = [];

}
```

I want to get the product ordered by price through ProductFilter model.

```
$filteredData = ProductFilter::with('products');
```

Product filter contains some more code to get the match. I have removed that. Through the products, relation sort the products according to price and get the records.

Here is the code that I have tried

```
 $filteredData = OcProductFilter::where('status',1);
 if($sort)
 $filteredData = $filteredData->with(['products' => function($query) use {
              $query->orderBy('price','DESC');         
             }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sortBy` method sorts the collection by the given key. The sorted collection keeps the original array keys

Try as below.

```
$filteredData = ProductFilter::with('products')->get()->sortByDesc('product.price');
```

more about [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-sortbydesc)